# Is previously initialize memory guaranteed to persist after a placement new call?

Tags: c++, c++11, placement-new

Say I have the following:

```
struct A
{
   int x;
};

//...
A* aOriginal = new A();  //value construct aOriginal
assert( aOriginal->x == 0 );

A* aSecond = new (aOriginal) A;
assert( aSecond->x == 0 );
```

Is the second assert guaranteed to hold, even though `aSecond` is not value-initialized? Logically, it should, because the memory isn't overwritten, but is it specified by the standard?

Comment: You are creating object twice on the same memory.

Comment: I would venture that this is undefined behavior anyway, because the lifetime of the first object has not ended. But that can probably fixed by calling the dtor.

Comment: @pmr: Not really the behavior is well defined because the object is a POD

Comment: I didn't even have this in mind when asking, but I guess I nailed it, since a POD expresses exactly what I had in mind :)

Comment: @pmr: 3.8/1 *The lifetime of an object of type T ends when:
— if T is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or — the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.* [As an answer to your request for a quote in a now deleted answer]

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: What is it that you want to do? I mean... if you want to ensure that the memory is not modified, why are you *recreating* the object with placement new in the first case?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas nothing practical, just asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

When you construct the second object on the same storage location, the lifetime of the previous one ends (§3.8/1):

> [...] The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when:
>
> - if `T` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (§12.4), the destructor call starts, or
> - the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.

When the second object is created, since `A` has the implicit default constructor, the `x` member is default-initialized, and thus no initialization is performed (§8.5/6):

> To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - [...]
> - otherwise, no initialization is performed.

And this means the object has indeterminate value (§5.3.4/15):

> A *new-expression* that creates an object of type `T` initializes that object as follows:
>
> - If the *new-initializer* is omitted, the object is *default-initialized* (§8.5); if no initialization is performed,
>   the object has indeterminate value.

And in case you think that the value is not indeterminate because you previously initialized another object on that storage location: the standard discards that possibility as well by saying the properties of the previous object no longer apply once its lifetime ends (§3.8/3):

> The properties ascribed to objects throughout this International Standard apply for a given object only during its lifetime.

Comment: I believe that the question is whether *no initialization* means that the memory is guaranteed not to be modified. Because placement new is being used, he wants to know if he can depend on the values not being modified after the construction of the new object.

Comment: I don't think that indeterminate value applies in this case because it was initialized before and should be well-defined unless initialization performed again. It doesn't seem like those who wrote the standard explicitly thought about this.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I thought "indeterminate value" was pretty clear you can't depend on it.

Comment: @Vlad No, the object that was initialized first *is gone* when the other one is initialized.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: How so? Can you elaborate on how a POD type can be technically "gone" if the memory where it is placed is not touched?

Comment: I think the ambiguity here is in the word "indeterminate", which is never really defined. Does it mean "always considered uninitialized ", or does it mean "considered uninitialized, unless previously initialized"? We know using an *uninitialized* value is undefined behavior, but it says nothing of using an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I added an explanation for that.

Comment: @GManNickG even if it's not UB, it is not guaranteed that the assert passes. FWIW (maybe not much) there's also a note on §17.6.3.4 saying "Operations involving indeterminate values may cause undefined behavior." More concretely, I believe implementations are allowed to write special values in these cases, for example for debugging.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: In theory there is no difference between theory and practice. But in practice there is. Your answer may be right according to a standard, but from pure technical perspective the assertion should hold true unless compiler generated some code to actually override that memory.

Comment: So then if we do this instead: `void* mem = ::operator new(sizeof(A)); (new (mem) A())->~A();`, we are guaranteed nothing about the contents of `mem`? It seems so unlike C++ for this to be so. :|

Comment: @GManNickG: You have explicitly destroyed the object, that might make a difference (VS writes bit patterns when an object is destroyed in debug mode, not sure if always or only sometimes). Now that is different from the case in the question, since there is no destructor involved to *end the lifetime* of the object (technically even for a POD, the explicit call to the destructor would not end the lifetime, its lifetime is bound by the memory it uses)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Is that another theory? A bit silly to argue from that perspective when the question is specifically asking for the 'theory' (someone elses's practice, of course...).

Comment: @VladLazarenko the question was *exactly* whether this was guaranteed by standard. I don't understand what you're trying to say there.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Good point, and important in that the entire question is centered around not having that...doh.