# Can operator new() initialize PODs before the constructor runs?

Tags: c++, new-operator, undefined-behavior

I think this question might be a duplicate, but I don't know how to search for it.

I'm trying to overload `operator new` so that I can allow for a variable-length buffer after my class. Does my current design work as intended, or is it undefined behavior?

If the answer differs in C++98, C++03, and C++11 then please explain the differences.

```
struct POD { /* ...other POD members here... */ };

struct BufferedPOD : POD
{
    size_t n;
    BufferedPOD()
    // Assume n is already initialized...
    {
    }

    static void *operator new(size_t size)
    {
        return ::operator new(size);
    }
    static void *operator new(size_t size, size_t additional_size)
    {
        void *const p = operator new(size + additional_size);
        static_cast<BufferedPOD *>(p)->n = additional_size;
        return p;
    }
    static void operator delete(void *p)
    {
        return ::operator delete(p);
    }
    static void operator delete(void *p, size_t)
    {
        return operator delete(p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<BufferedPOD> p(new (1000) BufferedPOD());
    foo(p.get());  // do something with buffer
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are relying on undefined behavior, [the memory is indeterminate upon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11729603) [calling the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27595793).

In debug builds, it will often be filled with some marker-pattern for easier debugging, in release builds this freedom is generally just used to speed up the construction.
In both, reading indeterminate objects gets you UB, however that will play out in detail.

Anyway, you are going at it the wrong way (let's ignore violation of the "rule of three" for the time being:

Just declare matching overloads for `::operator new` and `::operator delete`, and a factory-function (which should be the only code with access to the only ctor you leave usable) which uses that and passes the extra-space on:

```
void* operator new(size_t a, size_t b) {
    if(a+b< a || a+b < b)
        throw new std::bad_alloc("::operator new(size_t, size_t) too big");
    return operator new(a+b);
}
void operator delete(void* p, size_t a, size_t b) {return operator delete(p/*, a+b*/);}

struct Buffered : POD { // Not a pod due to inheritance
    Buffered* make(size_t extra) {return new(extra) Buffered(extra);}
private:
    size_t n;
    Buffered(size_t extra) : n(extra) {}
    Buffered(Buffered&) = delete;
    void operator=(Buffered&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: Why did you move those operator new/delete's outside the class?  Any particular reason?

Comment: First, reuse. Second, allowing deletion through a base-pointer, if you add a virtual dtor there onetime. Third, avoiding to code the other variants.

Comment: I see. +1. I'm still digesting this answer since I could swear I tried going in a similar direction before and hit a stumbling block, but I can't figure out what it is right now... in the meantime, where's the violation of the rule of 3 that you're talking about?

Comment: Simple, your bufferedthingy is depends on having the `n` following bytes for any use. But if you copy one to another, those additional bytes simply won't be there. BTW, I searched for `placement new [c++] initialized is:q`, and then went through a dozen or so posts.